How to get API response and put it in a column after clicking at a button in Microsoft Dynamics 365 F&O?
I created a very simple form in Microsoft D365 F&O:

A weatherTable(Location, Temperature) represented as a grid
A button above the grid

The system should work like this:
The location column can be edited and the user should enter a region, while the temperature column (read only) have to show the appropriate temperature based on the region after the user click the button.
This works with specific API that takes as parameter the region, and reply with a json file holding the details. I tested the API with postman and it worked well.


API endpoint: https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=5b6d44effc87449990c101000241405&aqi=no&**q=location**

Example of JSON response:


{
    "location": {
        "name": "New York",
        "region": "New York",
        "country": "United States of America",
        "lat": 40.71,
        "lon": -74.01,
        "tz_id": "America/New_York",
        "localtime_epoch": 1716281298,
        "localtime": "2024-05-21 4:48"
    },
    "current": {
        "last_updated_epoch": 1716281100,
        "last_updated": "2024-05-21 04:45",
        "**temp_c": 15.0**,
        "temp_f": 59.0,
        "is_day": 0,
        "condition": {
            "text": "Clear",
            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png",
            "code": 1000
        }
    }
}

All I want is temperature value to be filled with temp_c in the JSON response after reading the region from the location in the form and send it with the request as parameter.
I tried this code but I know it have a lot of code to add.
public void clicked()
{
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest request;
    System.IO.Stream stream;
    System.Exception sysEx;
    
    str URLAPI;
    str location;
    Query query;
    QueryRun queryRun;
    WeatherTable weatherTable;

    // Define a query to retrieve the location from WeatherTable
    query = new Query();

    // Create a query run
    queryRun = new QueryRun(query);

    // Run the query and retrieve the location value
    queryRun.next();
    WeatherTable = queryRun.get(tableNum(WeatherTable));
    location = weatherTable.Location;

    // Construct the API URL
    URLAPI = strFmt("https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=5b6d44effc87449990c101000241405&aqi=no&q=%1", location);

    // Create the HTTP request
    request = System.Net.WebRequest::Create(URLAPI) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = 'POST';
    request.ContentType = 'application/json';

    // Further code for handling the HTTP request...


    // Set the request headers
    //System.Net.WebHeaderCollection headerCollection = request.Headers;
    //headerCollection.Set('Name', 'Value');

    var utf8 = System.Text.Encoding::get_UTF8();


    // Set the request body
    var byteArrayPayload = utf8.GetBytes("{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}");
    try
    {
        // send out the payload
        using (System.IO.Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArrayPayload, 0, byteArrayPayload.Length);
        }

        // request.GetResponse() may already result in an error if the request was e.g. a Bad Request(Status Code 400). This should be handled upstream via our global error handling.
        using (System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
        {
            stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
            str responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (sysEx)
    {
        throw;
    }


Did you take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/consume-external-web-service? Also, while the general idea of your question is clear, the Stack Overflow Q&A format works best if you have one specific question. Currently, it is unclear what part exactly you are seeking an answer for.

Dear FH-Inway,
I ask questions on this platform for one and only goal: having an answer, and nobody is obligated to answer if the related person doesn't have a convenable answer.
So instead of judging me how to ask, or telling me how this platform works, you can just answer questions you know their answers, or just, give me an answer.
(My question cannot be clearer that this).

Is this form and for datasource the customized? (That means the form and the table are new.​ Not the extended element)

If yes, could we create a new TempDB table to store the data? If a user clicks the button, and gets the data from response, the form would construct the data again, and populate the data you wanted.

